# Jekyll Syntax Error Comment tag was never closed

Tags: jekyll

I've been using the same Header file for years but all of a sudden I'm getting the following error message: "Error: Liquid syntax error ..... _includes/header.html line 13): 'comment' tag was never closed included in /_layouts/default.html"

Line 13 has no comment tags, I've removed the two comment tags in my header file yet I still have the same issues.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out, turns out the open comment tag was not in my header file but in my nav file which is embedded into my header file if this helps anyone in the future.  The error message was a bit misleading.